# How to set blank cell as 0 during formula evaluation in Apache poi java

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi, evaluate

I have an xlsm file where few cells give cumulative results from 3 tables.

However, sometimes only 1 table has values and remaining 2 are blank.

So when I run formula evaluation in Apache poi on cumulative results table, I get Evaluation Exception since values in remaining 2 tables are blank.

Example

```
Cumulative cells D1, E1

D1 = CustomFunction(A1,B1)
E1 = IF(A1+B1+C1=0, do something)
/*
CustomFunction definition is added in a class which implements FreeRefFunction and added to workbook using workbook.addToolPack(udfToolPack). 
https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html 
*/

A1= 5
B1 = blank
C1 = blank
```

And if I did

```
evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cellD1);
evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cellE1);
```

I get the EvaluationException

```
org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.EvaluationException
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:69)
    at CustomFunction.evaluate(CustomFunction.java:22)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.UserDefinedFunction.evaluate(UserDefinedFunction.java:64)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:129)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:525)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:288)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:51)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:44)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:525)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:288)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:51)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:44)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:36)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:525)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:288)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:51)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:44)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:36)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:525)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:288)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:51)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:44)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.RelationalOperationEval.evaluate(RelationalOperationEval.java:64)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:525)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:288)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:230)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:264)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:151)
    at ExcelProcessor.main(ExcelProcessor.java:314)
```

CustomFunction.java

```
public class CustomFunction implements FreeRefFunction {
    public ValueEval evaluate( ValueEval[] args, OperationEvaluationContext ec ) {
        if (args.length != 2) {  
            return ErrorEval.VALUE_INVALID;
        }
        double val; 
        double result;
        int length;
        try {
            ValueEval v1 = OperandResolver.getSingleValue( args[0], 
                                                           ec.getRowIndex(), 
                                                           ec.getColumnIndex() ) ;
            ValueEval v2 = OperandResolver.getSingleValue( args[1], 
                                                           ec.getRowIndex(), 
                                                           ec.getColumnIndex() ) ;
            val = OperandResolver.coerceValueToDouble(v1) ; 
            length = OperandResolver.coerceValueToInt(v2);
            
            result = calculate( val, length) ;
            
            checkValue(result);
            
        } catch (EvaluationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace() ;
            return e.getErrorEval();
        }
        return new NumberEval( result ) ;
    }
    
    public double calculate( double val, int length) {
double retVal = 0.0; //some complex calculation
    return retVal;
    }
     static final void checkValue(double result) throws EvaluationException {
         if (Double.isNaN(result) || Double.isInfinite(result)) {
             throw new EvaluationException(ErrorEval.NUM_ERROR);
         }
     }
}
```

So, in formula evaluation, how do I consider blank values as 0?

Comment: Please show the exact `EvaluationException` (stacktrace). For the `=IF(A1+B1+C1=0,...)`-formula current `apache poi 5.0.0` evaluates even if `B1` and `C1` are blank. So not reproducible. For the `CustomFunction` we would at least need the definition.

Comment: Hey Axel, I don't think I have latest version of Apache poi, let me try once with the latest version. Thanks a lot for your comment, I will update the question with custom function definition.

Comment: Please show the exact `EvaluationException` (stacktrace) also.

Comment: Please check now @Axel Richter

Comment: What code line is `CustomFunction.java` code line 22? The stacktrace comes from `...} catch (EvaluationException e) { e.printStackTrace() ;...` and it shows that `OperandResolver` fails. So either `args[0]` or `args[1]` point to an error value itself. So either `A1` or `B1` contains an error value. Simply do not `e.printStackTrace()` and evaluator will return that error value as the result. What else should it return when `A1` or `B1` contains an error value?

Comment: Line 22 is OperandResolver.getSingleValue itself. I think I understood what you said in the above comment. I will check again and get back. Thanks a lot for your help. Although, I still have one question, if some input parameter is blank, what will args contain?

Comment: If formula is `=CustomFunction(A1,B1)`, as you told, the `ValueEval[] args` contain `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval[SheetName!A1]`and `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval[SheetName!B1]`. And if `A1` contains 5 and `B1` is blank, as you told, then `ValueEval v1` will be `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [5]` and `ValueEval v2`will be `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.BlankEval`. And no `EvaluationException` will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
=if(and(A1>0,B1>0,C1>0), do something,not something)
```

AND() makes sure that all 3 cells are greater than o, Excel considers blank as 0 but you may need to do an error check if the cells have spaces etc.

Comment: I understand excel considers blank as 0 but how to make Apache poi to consider blank as 0

Comment: You tagged Excel, so I gave you something for Excel...

Comment: Well it is excel using java Apache poi, question itself contains that

Comment: @Doofenshmirtz so use the logic and apply it where you want.

Comment: I can't change formula in excel file, I just have control over the java code, so like you said add "and", I can't do that